# Difference Between AWS SAVING PLAN Coverage Report vs Utilization Report

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

AWS SAVINGS PLAN:
I cannot differentiate between the Coverage Report and a Utilization Report.
However, I can see a difference in the report of both of these in my Billing account.
Utilization Report:

- 100% used in Savings Plan

Coverage Report:

- 68% used in Savings Plan

Queries:
What is the difference Between AWS SAVING PLAN Coverage Report vs Utilization Report?
Why one of the reports is showing 100% (Utilization Report) and the other 68% (Coverage Report)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps:

**Utilization Report**: Measures the amount of the savings plan you are using. If it's less than 100% it means that you reserved more than you need.

**Coverage Report**: Measures the percentage of your costs covered by the savings plan. If it's less than 100%, you can increase your savings plan to optimize costs.

Ideally, both should be 100%, but I would say that it's more important to keep the utilization report at 100% because it's already a fixed cost that you already acquired. The coverage report indicates further improvement opportunities to reduce costs.

Here you can find the official information from AWS documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/latest/userguide/ce-sp-usingPR.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/latest/userguide/ce-sp-usingCR.html

Answer (score 0):

- `Utilization = SP Actual Usage / SP Purchase`

  - Of all the SP you bought, how much have you used?
- `Coverage = SP Actual Usage / SP-eligible Usage`

  - How much of your SP-eligible usage is covered by SP?

[image]